# Orientdb distributed mode .Net Client error

Tags: .net, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have OrientDB Community Edition v2.2.8 setup in distributed mode with 2 nodes with a load balancer (F5) in front. I have a .net app using the .net client (OrientDB-Net.binary.Innov8tive.0.1.11) to write to the datbase. When the app tries to save to the database I get this error

```
Orient.Client.OException: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedConfigurationChangedException: Local node 'app04' is not the master for cluster 'firm' (it is 'app03')
    DB name="TESTDB"
```

I tried connecting to the load balanced url and also the nodes directly. I get the same error always. I'm saving 2 different types of vertices and one edge between these 2 vertices. Depending on the node I'm trying to connect I get an error on one of the objects thats not on that particular node. 
I'm creating the connection in my app like this

```
  using (ODatabase database = new ODatabase(_hostname, _port, _databaseName, ODatabaseType.Graph, _username, _password, _databaseAlias))
  {
      .....
      .....
  }
```

I couldn't find any specific setting for distributed mode on the .net client. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Hi, that error is saying that the node app04 is not the master and that you have to use app03 that is the master, anyway there is a more recent version of OrientDB-Net.binary.Innov8tive (0.1.6) have you tried?

Comment: I'm using the most recent version OrientDB-Net.binary.Innov8tive (0.1.11) .  I understand the error but should the client api be cognizant of those and redirect the request?